# Get the last message postgres

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql

I'm using Laravel to build something like a chat, i'd like to get the last message from user X and Y:

I have this table called "messages"

```
id integer
receiver_id integer references user
sender_id integer references user
message text
created_at datetime
```

Here I have a the message, when and who send the message;

```
       $user = JWTAuth::toUser();
       $messages = DB::table("messages")
            ->select(DB::raw(
                "least(sender_id, receiver_id) as user_1,
               greatest(sender_id, receiver_id) as user_2,
               max(created_at) as last_timestamp,
               max(message) as message"))
            ->where("sender_id", $user->id)
            ->orWhere("receiver_id", $user->id)
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("least(sender_id, receiver_id), greatest(sender_id, receiver_id)"))
            ->orderBy("last_timestamp", "desc")
            ->get();

    $message_info = array();

    foreach($messages as $k => $m) {
        $message_info[$k]['message'] = $m->message;
        $message_info[$k]['last_message'] = $m->last_timestamp;
        if($m->user_2 == $user->id){
            $message_info[$k]['user_id'] = $m->user_1;
        }else{
            $message_info[$k]['user_id'] = $m->user_2;
        }
    }
```

Here I list the users that have messages

```
    $listUserHaveMessage = [];

    foreach ($messages as $message){
        if($message->user_2 == $user->id){
            $listUserHaveMessage[] = $message->user_1;
        }else{
            $listUserHaveMessage[] = $message->user_2;
        }
    }
```

And here the users that not have send messages

```
    $notMessage = User::where("client_id",'=',$user->client_id)
        ->where("id","!=", $user->id)
        ->where("is_visible",'=', true)
        ->whereNotIn("id", $listUserHaveMessage)
        ->get();
    foreach ($notMessage as $m){
        $listUserNotHaveMessage[] = $m->id;
    }
```

Now I make the merge of arrays and a query to get all users

```
    $list_users = array_merge($listUserHaveMessage, $listUserNotHaveMessage);
    $idsImploded = implode(',',$list_users);
    $users = User::where("client_id",'=',$user->client_id)
        ->where("id","!=", $user->id)
        ->where("is_visible",'=', true)
        ->whereIn("id", $list_users)
        ->orderByRaw(DB::raw("position(id::text in '$idsImploded')"))
        ->get();

    $outPut = array();

    foreach($users as $k => $u){
        $outPut['usuarios'][$k] = $u;
    }
```

My question is:
How to merge the last message to User array??
There is a way to do it??

Thanks

Comment: Hello, i think your can return a payload like that (in json) : ```{"user": {}, "message": {}}```

Comment: Heyy :) 
But i think i need merge the arrays, using user_id, because the message belongs to a user

Comment: imagine you have two arrays: `$user` and `$message` you can do `$output = array_merge($user, $message)` see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php